# Initialise fabric ca with modified fabric-server-config

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am using the docker-compose for running the fabric ca as shown below. I want to start the fabric ca with updated fabric-ca-server.config file. I have fabric-ca-server-config, i have modified it, I want to initialise when i run the docker. please suggest me.

```
ca0:
image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
environment:
  - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/_sk
ports:
  - "7054:7054"
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/_SK-b admin:adminpw -d'
volumes:
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
container_name: ca_peerOrg1
networks:
  - byfn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@fama,

You can pass your configuration file path to the below command

```
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw --cafiles /ca/ca1/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
```

### Mount the file path like below

```
volumes:
  - ./ca/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml: /ca/ca1/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
```